# Azure Build Pipeline Bash Script now setting build variable properly

Tags: bash, azure, azure-pipelines

I have a Bash script in my build pipeline that will set some build variables depending on which branch triggered The build. However when I try to echo these variables in another bash script some of them don't echo.

Set Environment Variables:

```
if [[ $(Build.SourceBranchName) == 'develop' ]]; then
  echo $TagVersion
  echo $(Build.BuildId)

    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion;]$TagVersion'
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=ChangeSet;]$(Build.BuildId)'
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=Environment;]DEVTEST'
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfig;]Debug'

fi
```

This has a output of:

```
v1.4.0 
7090
```

Set Version:

```
echo $(AppVersion)
echo $(ChangeSet)
echo $(Environment)
echo $(BuildConfig)
```

This outputs

```
7090
DEVTEST
Debug
```

Why is the AppVersion now writing to the console?

Comment: Where do you configure the `$TagVersion` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$()` syntax is evaluated by the Agent before bash sees it, while the `$`var is evaluated by bash. This is why ChangeSet is correctly assigned.

The `echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion;]$TagVersion'` command uses a single quote (`'`) which stops bash from interpreting the content. To expand the variable use a double quote (`"`), that is `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion;]$TagVersion"`